# How should I auto log someone away out of my site?

Tags: javascript, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4

So I'm building a website in MVC4, and I have a series of services, of which I have built a into a dll which wraps all of the calls and automatically changes the xml into specified objects. So instead of receiving xml a caller would receive a CustomReturn object which has an ErrorCode, ErrorMessage, Token, and Payload, of which the payload will already be translated into say a List etc.

Now, to make 90% of the calls to our backend services a Token is required, and on return of a successful call a new Token will be returned. To manage this Token it is stored in a cookie which is passed with each call, this way the server handles managing the Token rather than having the browser javascript do it.

So i have created an attribute which sits at the top of my controllers which looks for this cookie, decrypts the Token and stores it within a custom HttpContext.Current.User.

Finally, my controller functions basically look like so:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public T MyFunction(string venue)
    {
        var asr = Services.GetSomething(Token, venue);
        SetAuthTicket(asr.Token);
        return asr.Payload;
    }
```

Sorry for the long back story, but here's where my question comes in:

On my page I have a feature which gets and displays data upon user request, and then will auto update that same data every 30 seconds.

I wish to implement a auto logout feature within the page that detects that a user hasnt made a request in x time and logs them out...

Originally I was going to do this by verifying the Token, as after x time it become invalid.

But currently the auto updates are keeping the Token valid since they make the same call which resets the Token...

**Question**

What would be the best option for implementing a auto logout feature in my site? Should I create a seperate copy of the calls which wont reset the Token? or should I write some javascript which would detect mouse movement or clicks or something and log them out that way?

Comment: how about flag your per 30 seconds request? such as add the head or whatever to indicate the request is fired by javascript, and thus doesn't update the timer/token?.  Requests from user wouldn't have this flag, and keep timer/token updated

Comment: How would you recommend I implement that flag? I would prefer if it wasn't an additional parameter in my functions signature, is there a way that I could add something to a ajax call that I could look for that would indicate that without changing my current setup?

Comment: just append some parameter to your ajax "get" request, such as "source=js". At server side, you can tell this is a automatic request if it Request["source"] == "js"

Comment: Ok Thanks, if you could turn you comment into an answer I will gladly accept it as it sounds like a nice way to handle my situtaion

Comment: yeah, put into an answer now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about **flag** your per 30 seconds request? such as add the head or whatever to indicate the request is fired by javascript, and thus doesn't update the timer/token?.

Requests from user wouldn't have this flag, and keep timer/token updated

Example, append some parameter to your ajax "get" request, such as `"source=js"`. At server side, you can tell this is a automatic request if it `Request["source"] == "js"`